# Stop React 18 from injecting bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a redirect on my site for anyone using IE 11. I'm using ES6 and some packages that just don't play well with IE.

I think it's related to some package updates, but previous code I had to load a simple message saying to use another browser was functioning.

I now get an error saying there is a syntax error in bundle.js, and the screen is blank. What surprises me is that it's loading the bundle at all. When I debug, I can see its injecting <script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js" And I think it's the page trying to load this first and erroring out that is causing my issue.

Is there any way to stop this injection? Anyone experienced with React and IE 11 that thinks this might be a red herring and I'm going in the wrong direction to fix this?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

I tried removing almost all my code out of index.html and would have expected that the page would ReactDOM.render a really simple message. It does not. It seems to error out before it really renders anything at all.

Comment: I don't believe IE11 is supported in React 18. [Check their site](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html).